# CTA button placement in the bottom of page using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have to edit a website using just vanilla javascript.
I have to overlay a dropdown menu with a CTA button that when pressed activates said menu.

I tried hiding the dropdown menu by setting css property to `hidden`, and added a button with "on click" event to make the menu `visible` again (all of this on Chrome dev console), but when adding the button element to document body it appends at the very end of page.

I tried using `insertBefore` but i cannot get it to work that way. Any better suggestions/help on how to approach this problem , or what I'm doing wrong in the `insertBefore` statement would be greatly appreciated.

```
const btn = document.createElement('Button');
btn.innerText='BUTTON';
btn.addEventListener('click',() =>{ BookingFormContent.style.visibility = 'visible';}); 
document.body.insertBefore(BookingForrm,btn);
```

error statement that follows is :

> Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node': The
> node before which the new node is to be inserted is not a child of
> this node.
> at :1:15

this is my first time messing with DOMs, so i might not be doing stuff right somewhere else.

Comment: Have you try to search your error here or on google. Make some search before asking

Comment: How are you defining BookingFormContent  and BookingForrm (I note the double r). Please make a working snippet so we can see the problem for ourselves.